# JavaScript jQuery currency conversion math problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, currency

I'm using an online currency converter. The base conversion is stuck on Euro which means I get the conversion rate for a specific currency when exchanged with Euros.

For example:

1 Euro = 1.2nn Dollars.

How can I use this output to change it to USD as a base output?

Here is the json output from the online currency converter:

```
{"success":true,"timestamp":1613901367,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-02-21","rates":{"AED":4.45116,"AFN":93.99,"ALL":123.72,"AMD":635.578463,"ANG":2.1788,"AOA":790.667826,"ARS":108.0972,"AUD":1.539803,"AWG":2.181285,"AZN":2.064913,"BAM":1.95583,"BBD":2.4508,"BDT":102.7685,"BGN":1.9559,"BHD":0.457,"BIF":2359.519995,"BMD":1.211825,"BND":1.6071,"BOB":8.3936,"BRL":6.523138,"BSD":1.2138,"BTC":2.1418808e-5,"BTN":88.0211,"BWP":13.151,"BYN":3.1438,"BYR":23751.769953,"BZD":2.4467,"CAD":1.528778,"CDF":2396.388683,"CHF":1.086092,"CLF":0.031122,"CLP":858.760264,"CNY":7.860871,"COP":4305.799991,"CRC":742.739999,"CUC":1.211825,"CUP":32.113362,"CVE":110.265,"CZK":25.89155,"DJF":216.09,"DKK":7.43649,"DOP":70.293,"DZD":160.694103,"EGP":18.954,"ERN":18.177809,"ETB":48.8765,"EUR":1,"FJD":2.455097,"FKP":0.864755,"GBP":0.86457,"GEL":4.011614,"GGP":0.864755,"GHS":7.0098,"GIP":0.864755,"GMD":62.348868,"GNF":12314.299975,"GTQ":9.3707,"GYD":253.949999,"HKD":9.395527,"HNL":29.251,"HRK":7.570882,"HTG":88.522,"HUF":358.451823,"IDR":17045.999966,"ILS":3.963928,"IMP":0.864755,"INR":87.923119,"IQD":1770.969996,"IRR":51023.89195,"ISK":155.602954,"JEP":0.864755,"JMD":182.978,"JOD":0.858341,"JPY":127.873596,"KES":133.1593,"KGS":102.562857,"KHR":4937.79999,"KMF":492.49028,"KPW":1090.642049,"KRW":1340.327385,"KWD":0.366703,"KYD":1.0116,"KZT":506.699999,"LAK":11340.799977,"LBP":1835.499996,"LKR":237.3028,"LRD":209.646147,"LSL":17.802172,"LTL":3.578205,"LVL":0.733021,"LYD":5.4041,"MAD":10.8062,"MDL":21.3451,"MGA":4575.569991,"MKD":61.615,"MMK":1711.493497,"MNT":3460.137548,"MOP":9.6935,"MRO":432.621316,"MUR":48.17,"MVR":18.666638,"MWK":945.162998,"MXN":24.75421,"MYR":4.894608,"MZN":90.996397,"NAD":17.802166,"NGN":461.705741,"NIO":42.362,"NOK":10.256649,"NPR":140.834,"NZD":1.658558,"OMR":0.46658,"PAB":1.2139,"PEN":4.4329,"PGK":4.3166,"PHP":58.765,"PKR":193.1196,"PLN":4.48509,"PYG":8071.099984,"QAR":4.412301,"RON":4.87643,"RSD":117.56,"RUB":89.71751,"RWF":1205.469998,"SAR":4.544348,"SBD":9.702984,"SCR":26.056,"SDG":66.983673,"SEK":10.031856,"SGD":1.6064,"SHP":0.864755,"SLL":12378.792761,"SOS":710.129859,"SRD":17.152217,"STD":24578.396965,"SVC":10.622,"SYP":621.394433,"SZL":17.808,"THB":36.336619,"TJS":13.8315,"TMT":4.241387,"TND":3.280456,"TOP":2.790353,"TRY":8.43879,"TTD":8.2351,"TWD":33.844944,"TZS":2814.859994,"UAH":33.8042,"UGX":4452.299991,"USD":1.211825,"UYU":51.976,"UZS":12784.009975,"VEF":12.103107,"VND":27941.999944,"VUV":130.026527,"WST":3.060192,"XAF":655.956999,"XAG":0.044427,"XAU":0.000679,"XCD":3.275018,"XDR":0.8432,"XOF":655.956999,"XPF":119.546977,"YER":303.410729,"ZAR":17.756878,"ZMK":10907.883522,"ZMW":26.2975,"ZWL":390.208051}}
```

I want the rates to reflect USD as the base output:

IE: 1 USD = 0.82nn Euro, nn ZAR, nn Other currency.

Can one use this output to do the conversion?

Comment: you have a json with all value linked to EUROs and you want another json with all values linked to USD?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the json from EURO to USD:

```js
var s = '{"success":true,"timestamp":1613901367,"base":"EUR","date":"2021-02-21","rates":{"AED":4.45116,"AFN":93.99,"ALL":123.72,"AMD":635.578463,"ANG":2.1788, "EUR": 1, "USD": 1.211825}}';

var t = JSON.parse(s);
var rates = t['rates'];
var base = t['base']

var result = convertTo('USD');
console.log(result);
function convertTo(devise){
  var v = rates[base] / rates[devise];

  for (const key in rates) {
    t['rates'][key] *= v;
  }
  t['base']=devise; 
  return JSON.stringify(t);  
}
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy.. In this JSON array 1 EURO = "USD":1.211825; && 1 EUR = "ZAR":17.756878 and so on... How to dynamically get your "v" value in your example for 1 USD || What is the "v" value as in where did you get it? In other words i think i need the reverse of this: 1 EURO = "USD":1.211825; first to get the "v" value above. How can i get it? I'm thinking percentages but ..

Comment: as in this: var usdRate = t['rates']['EUR'] / ;t['rates']['USD']; "V" value = usdRates.. The result seems more or less correct..

Comment: This works perfectly -- Thank you Frenchy.. I cant vote you up wont allow me too but your answer is spot on.. Greets

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the conversion rates for USD from the converter, as the conversion rates are determined on a currency to currency level.

Comment: To do this it becomes a pay service of $80 per month. The base is fixed on EUR..